# Assign a CommandButtton to Upload a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to create a commandbutton to Upload/Open an existing workbook as a source file to run my macro, I tried to find some answer but didn't find much success as of yet. This is how it looks right now

[image]

I wanted to know if it is possible to create to a commandButton to open or upload an existing workbook using the vba in excel, Any help would be appreciate it^^

Comment: Upload to where?  If you want your user to be able to select a file then you should look at `Application.GetOpenFileName`

Answer (score 0):

The picture failed to display on my machine, so I guess there are two situations you want to execute the program as:

1. Just open another Excel file then copy data manually.
2. Automatically read data from another Excel as the source data.

For first one, you can use `FileDialog` and `Workbooks.Open` to open target Excel file. The code would be like:

```
Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
Dim selectedItem As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook

Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fileDialog
    .Title = "Select a Excel file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo ExitCode
    selectedItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True 
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(selectedItem, True, False)

ExitCode:
Set fileDialog = Nothing
```

Then for second one, you can use `FileDialog` and `ADODB Connection` to load source data to current file.

```
Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
Dim selectedItem As String 
Dim excelConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim excelRst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim excelStrConn As String
Dim excelStrSQL As String

Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fileDialog
    .Title = "Select a Excel file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo ExitCode
    selectedItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

excelStrConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" + selectedItem + ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""
excelConn.Open excelStrConn
excelStrSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
Set excelRst = excelConn.Execute(excelStrSQL)
Worksheets("Sheet1$").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset excelRst
excelRst.Close: excelConn.Close

ExitCode:
Set fileDialog = Nothing
```